# Sharepoint Designer doesn't show all forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm a bit confused as to why Sharepoint designer doesn't show all of the forms for a document library... If I open the document library in SPD, I get the following:
[image]

However, If I navigate to the Document Library in the browser, and click "modify view in sharepoint desginer(advanced)", it brings me to this page:
[image]

Which, if I click on "forms" in the breadcrumbs above, takes me to this page:
[image]

Why wouldn't SPD just show me all of these? It seems convoluted that I have to access the forms in this way. I can't access allItems.aspx in any other way, unless you guys know another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, on the first image that you posted, the forms are separated from the views. You're looking for a view, so you should look at the top right of the page. It's just a way for SPD to organize pages according to their usage.

[image]

You can also view all the forms/views together if you click "All Files" from the left navigation in SPD, then click the name of your list/library, then click Forms. So you don't really need to open SP for that.

Comment: That makes sense, what I don't fully understand is the View "all documents" is an HTML page. But, if I go to "All Items", it is an aspx page.

Comment: It just says HTML in the UI, but it is in fact .aspx as SharePoint won't use plain HTML pages for its content as it uses server controls inside.

Comment: can I add scriptlinks to the aspx? if so, where should i add them?

Comment: This is a SharePoint view. You can edit the view in browser, and add a script editor webpart, add your scripts there.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but if I add the script editor to the document library's page... And then put the document library on some page, will the script still run on said page?

Comment: You don't put the document library anywhere, when you open the library, it will open the default view that you have, which is All Documents that you see in SharePoint Designer. Edit that page and add the script editor webpart, the script will be added for that view. If you have multiple views, you would need to choose your view from the browser, and add the script editor to that page/view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50854/discussion-between-sabien-ambrose-and-mohamed-derhalli).